# Square payment integrating in laravel gives error ["detail":"Must supply amount_money","field":"amount_money"}]

Tags: php, laravel, square

**MY FRONTEND:**

```
<script type="module">
        const payments = Square.payments('xxxxxx', 'xxxxx');
        const card = await payments.card();
        await card.attach('#card-container');

        const cardButton = document.getElementById('card-button');
        cardButton.addEventListener('click', async () => {
        const statusContainer = document.getElementById('payment-status-container');

        try {
            const result = await card.tokenize();
            if (result.status === 'OK') {
            console.log(`Payment token is ${result.token}`);
            statusContainer.innerHTML = "Payment Successful";

            var token = result.token;

                $.ajaxSetup({
                    headers: {
                        'X-CSRF-TOKEN': $('meta[name="csrf-token"]').attr('content')
                    }
                });

            $.ajax({
                    url: '/payment-square',
                    type: 'POST',
                    data: {
                        token: token,
                        // add any other payment details you want to send to the server
                    },
                    success: function(response) {
                        console.log(response);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr) {
                        console.log(xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });

            } else {
            let errorMessage = `Tokenization failed with status: ${result.status}`;
            if (result.errors) {
                errorMessage += ` and errors: ${JSON.stringify(
                result.errors
                )}`;
            }

            throw new Error(errorMessage);
            }
        } catch (e) {
            console.error(e);
            statusContainer.innerHTML = "Payment Failed";
        }
        });
    </script>
```

**CONTROLLER**:

```
<?php

   namespace App\Http\Controllers;

   use Illuminate\Http\Request;
   use Square\SquareClient;
   use Square\LocationsApi;
   use Square\Exceptions\ApiException;
   use Square\Http\ApiResponse;
   use Square\Models\ListLocationsResponse;
   use Square\Models\Money;
    use Square\Models\CreatePaymentRequest;
   use Square\Models\createPayment;
   use Square\Environment;
   use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

   class SquarePaymentController extends Controller
   {
    public function initiatePayment(Request $request)
    {
        $square_client = new SquareClient([
            'accessToken' => 'xxxxxxxxx',
            'environment' => 'sandbox',
            'additionalHeaders' => [
                'Authorization' => 'Bearer xxxxxx',
            ],
        ]);

        $locationId = 'LYQ8QF8RS568Z';

        $payments_api = $square_client->getPaymentsApi();

        $money = new Money();
        $money->setAmount(100*100);
        $money->setCurrency("USD");

        $data = $request->input('token');

        $orderId = rand(9000, 1000);
        $create_payment_request = new CreatePaymentRequest($data, $orderId,$money);

        $response = $payments_api->createPayment($create_payment_request);

        if ($response->isSuccess()) {
        echo json_encode($response->getResult());
        } else {
        echo json_encode($response->getErrors());
        }
    }
}
```

**THE ERROR I AM FACING IS:**`your text`

> [{"category":"INVALID_REQUEST_ERROR","code":"MISSING_REQUIRED_PARAMETER","detail":"Must
> supply amount_money","field":"amount_money"}] no matter how I set the
> money object to the request it returns me the same error. PLease
> anyone could help meout of this I am stuck loong now . Note that I
> have use correct access token, location id and client id . here while
> sharing I have made it to xxxxx

Answer (score 0):

Try with this code.

Make sure to replace "YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN", "YOUR_NONCE", and the "amount" value with your own values. Also, make sure to handle the success and error response accordingly in the try-catch block.

```
use Square\SquareClient;
use Square\Models\CreatePaymentRequest;
use Square\Exceptions\ApiException;

$client = new SquareClient([
    'accessToken' => 'YOUR_ACCESS_TOKEN',
    'environment' => 'sandbox', // or 'production'
]);

$request_body = new CreatePaymentRequest([
    'source_id' => 'YOUR_NONCE',
    'amount_money' => [
        'amount' => 100, // replace with your amount
        'currency' => 'USD',
    ],
    'idempotency_key' => uniqid(),
]);

try {
    $response = $client->paymentsApi()->createPayment($request_body);
    // handle success response
} catch (ApiException $e) {
    // handle error response
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```